# Adjoint of the direct sum of operators vs. direct sum of their adjoints

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, unbounded-operators, normal-operator

Let $\mathcal{H}$ be an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space which decomposes as the direct sum of a countable family of Hilbert spaces $\{\mathcal{H}_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, namely
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{H}=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\mathcal{H}_n.
\end{equation}
For all $n$, let $A_n$ be a (possibly unbounded) densely defined operator on $\mathcal{H}_n$, with domain $\mathcal{D}(A_n)$. Define
\begin{equation}
A=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n,
\end{equation}
that is, $A$ is the operator on $\mathcal{H}$ with domain
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{D}(A)=\left\{\Psi=\{\psi_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}:\,\psi_n\in\mathcal{D}(A_n),\,\sum_n\|A_n\psi_n\|^2<\infty\right\}.
\end{equation}
acting as $A\psi_n=A_n\psi_n$.

Here is my question. Let $A^*$, $A^*_n$ be the adjoints of $A$ and $A_n$ respectively. Under which conditions does the equality
\begin{equation}
A^*=\bigoplus_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A^*_n
\end{equation}
hold? This is certainly true for self-adjoint operators, as stated e.g. by Reed and Simon (*Methods of Modern Mathematical Physics vol 4: Analysis of Operators*, Theorem XIII.85): if each $A_n$ is self-adjoint, then so is $A$. However, here I'm interested in what happens in the non-self-adjoint case; the proof in the reference only works for self-adjoint operators.

I have the "feeling" that the equation above should hold as well, possibly up to a closure, at least for sufficiently well-behaved operators (e.g. normal operators), but right now I have not found any reference about this case, nor I have managed to show that by directly applying the definition of adjoint. Indeed, by definition, $A^*$ has domain
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{D}(A^*)=\left\{\Psi=\{\psi_n\}_n\in\mathcal{H}:\;\forall\Phi=\{\phi_n\}_n\in\mathcal{D}(A)\,\exists\tilde{\Psi}=\{\tilde{\psi}_n\}_n\in\mathcal{H}\,\text{s.t.}\sum_n\left\langle\psi_n,A_n\phi_n\right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_n}=\sum_n\left\langle\tilde{\psi}_n,\phi_n\right\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_n}\right\}
\end{equation}
and $A^*\psi_n=\tilde{\psi}_n$, with $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_{\mathcal{H}_n}$ being the scalar product on $\mathcal{H}_n$. Whether this operator does correspond to the direct sum of the adjoints $A^*_n$ is not clear to me, since the equality on the two sums does not imply, in general, the equality between each term of the sums.

Comment: Is it clear that $A$ is densely defined at all?

Comment: In fact, it is not clear to me whether $A$ is densely defined (and thus whether it admits an adjoint at all). However, Theorem XIII.85 in the book referenced in my question seems not to worry about that, simply stating that the direct sum (in fact, direct integral with respect to any good measure) of self-adjoint operators is a self-adjoint operator.

Comment: I think a common number in the resolvent sets $\lambda_0\in\rho(A_n)$ would help a lot. You have that for self-adjoint operators.

Comment: It might be useful to note that in Thm XIII.85 of Reed and Simon, we assumed that each $A_n$ is densely defined. This is so that we can speak about their adjoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is true without any further assumptions.

If every $A_n$ is densely defined, then $A$ is densely defined: The set of vectors with finitely many non-zero components in the direct sum decomposition is dense in $\mathcal H$, and every vector with finitely many non-zero components can clearly be approximated by elements in the domain of $A$.

If $\xi\in D\left(\bigoplus_n A_n^\ast\right)$ and $\eta\in D(A)$, then
$$
\langle\xi,A\eta\rangle=\sum_n \langle \xi_n,A_n \eta_n\rangle=\sum_n\langle A_n^\ast\xi_n,\eta_n\rangle=\langle(\bigoplus_nA_n^\ast)\xi,\eta\rangle.
$$
Thus $\xi\in D(A^\ast)$ and $A^\ast \xi=(\bigoplus_n A_n^\ast)\xi$.

It remains to prove $D(A^\ast)\subset D(\bigoplus_n A_n^\ast)$. Let $\xi \in D(A^\ast)$ and $\eta\in D(A)$ such that $\eta_n=0$ for $n\neq k$. Then
$$
\langle (A^\ast\xi)_k,\eta_k\rangle=\langle A^\ast\xi,\eta\rangle=\langle \xi,A\eta\rangle=\langle \xi_k,A_k\eta_k\rangle.
$$
Thus $\xi_k\in D(A_k^\ast)$ and $(A^\ast \xi)_k=A_k^\ast\xi_k$. In particular,
$$
\sum_k \|A_k^\ast\xi_k\|^2=\sum_k\|(A^\ast \xi)_k\|^2=\|A^\ast \xi\|^2<\infty.
$$
Hence $\xi\in D(\bigoplus_n A_n^\ast)$.

Answer (score 0):

The situation can be more complex. For example, consider $A$ to be the momentum operator on the line, with a  potential in the origin. Such operator has a family of self-adjoint extensions, take one of them. It can be seen as the direct sum of two momentum operators on half-lines $A^-$, $A^+$, with appropriate transmission conditions between the two half-lines. Each operator is not self-adjoint. Indeed, their minimal operators have defect indeces (0,1) and (1,0)) but the minimal operator of $A$ has defect indices (1,1). So, the starting operator is self-adjoint, $A=A^*$ but $A^\pm \neq A^{\pm *}$.

Comment: This is an interesting example, but I think it does not apply here. We are defining $A^-\oplus A^+$ as the operator with domain $\mathcal{D}(A^-)\oplus\mathcal{D}(A^+)=\{(\psi_-,\psi_+):\psi_-\in\mathcal{D}(A^-),\psi_+\in\mathcal{D}(A^+)\}$. This does not leave room for a transmission condition between the two half-lines.